# distinguish between file and directory using java

Tags: java, file, filepath, dir

I have rather a very basic question but somehow it is confusing to me. Normally to check the existence of both file and directory we can do so by using boolean `file.exists()`
However i am wondering, is there any way that one can determine if given path is a directory or a file.

It would be nice if you can provide some short example using java.

Comment: Maybe with the `.isDirectory()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [from the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29), there are the methods `isFile` and `isDirectory`

Comment: @Johnydep - perhaps you should spend a few hours browsing the Javadocs for the Java class library.  Start with java.lang.*, then read java.io.*, java.util.*, java.net.* ... and other stuff that is relevant to the kind of Java programming that you do.

Comment: @StephenC, thanks actually i had problem with Eclipse IDE, otherwise for built in libraries mostly all the methods are visible with documentation, and i had no idea about these methods, sure i would, thanks again.

Comment: A good rule when learning a new language. If something that should be simple is hard, you've missed something.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [isDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29) and [isFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile%28%29).